# XText - How to check syntax violation in next line

Tags: xtext

I have a problem with xtext.
Basicly I try to create a whitespace sensitive language.
This is what my grammer should allow:

```
Title
Message
   Signal 1
   Signal 2
   Struct
      Signal 3
   Signal 4
```

And this should be not allowed.

```
    Title
Message
   Signal 1
      Signal 2
   Struct
      Signal 3
   Signal 4
```

So the problem is that Signal 1 is one level above Signal 2.
But going to the next level is only allowed for structs.

I have no plan how to check wether the next line is on the same level or not.
Can you give me a hint or a similar code snippet?

Thanks

Comment: Could you show us the corresponding snippet of your grammar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the newest xtext version xtext supports whitespace sensitive languages.

There are two synthetic tokens, BEGIN and END which can increase or decrease the indentation.

```
    // The following synthetic tokens are used for the indentation-aware blocks
terminal BEGIN:
    'synthetic:BEGIN'; // increase indentation
terminal END:
    'synthetic:END'; // decrease indentation
```

For an example watch the homeautomation example delivered with xtext.

Answer (score 1):

The grammar you are trying to achieve is a python-like grammar, that is, a grammar that allows to define block scopes based in text indentation. [Here](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=451838) you can find a discussion on this topic with some interesting links.

If you follow the links, you will find [xtextadd](https://github.com/martinbaker/xtextadd), which is a draft implementation of this kinds of specifications, including a great (really, very complete) [tutorial](https://github.com/martinbaker/xtextadd/tree/master/pbase) explaining every detail you should be aware of if you plan to implement the indentation-based-blocks feature. You can also find very helpful classes such as [PythonTerminals.xtext](https://github.com/martinbaker/xtextadd/blob/master/whitespaceblock/com.euclideanspace.whitespaceblock/src/com/euclideanspace/whitespaceblock/common2/PythonTerminals.xtext) and [PythonesqueTokenSource.java](https://github.com/martinbaker/xtextadd/blob/master/whitespaceblock/com.euclideanspace.whitespaceblock/src/com/euclideanspace/whitespaceblock/PythonesqueTokenSource.java). This is a very good starting point for your project.

The author of these contributions is [martinbaker](https://github.com/martinbaker).